# Manage Spring Security access page with specific role

Tags: java, spring

I need to manage the access too different jsp pages based on the role of the user that accesses it.

So let's say that I wanna access adminPage. If this method is accesed having admin role then i should
be able to return the page, otherwise not.

So I have this controller:

`@Controller
public class SpringSecurityController`

inside this controller I have this method which return me the requested page:

```
@RequestMapping("admin") //this does not work
public String getAdminPage()
{
    return "adminPage";
}
```

The trick is that i want to be capable to set this level of authorization as annotation to the getAdminPage() method in the given controller without any web xml settings or any other xml settings involved.

Help is much needed!

Comment: Are you looking for Secured annotation ? You can use it like this @Secured ({"ROLE_ADMIN"})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Secured](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.2.2.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/annotation/Secured.html) Annotation. Annotate `getAdminPage()` with `@Secured ({"ROLE_ADMIN"})` , If you want multiple roles then seprate them via comma like this

```
@Secured ({"ROLE_USER", "ROLE_ADMIN"}) 
public String getAdminPage()
{
    return "adminPage";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first try with slash

```
@RequestMapping("/admin")
```